# How do I reference different DLLs in Kaxaml

Tags: xaml, xaml-tools, kaxaml

I want to work with a DataGrid in Kaxaml.  How do I reference the toolkit dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mapping custom classes and namespaces in XAML using the **clr-namespace/assembly** notation, you can't specify the path of the assembly containing the class but just the assembly's name (more details can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies)), since all referenced assemblies must be linked during the XAML compilation via the project file.

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) doesn't support the concept of a project since it doesn't do any compilation but rather dynamically parses and renders the XAML entered in the editor "on-the-fly" by using the **System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader** class.

This means that when using Kaxaml you can only reference classes contained in the assemblies that are part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: This answer is partially wrong. You can reference other assemblies by importing the namespace and copying the assembly to Kaxaml's current directory.

Answer (score 18):

1. Copy WPFToolkit.dll to "C:\Program Files\Kaxaml\"

   - Restart Kaxaml

Now you can use such namespace:

```
xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to make a junction and add a probing path to Kaxaml's config.

**Make Junction to code**

- run elevated cmd
- cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Kaxaml"
- mklink /J ProbeFolder "c:\path-to-your-code"

**Modify Kaxaml.exe.config**

- run elevated notepad
- open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaxaml\Kaxaml.exe.config"
- add the following to the <configuration>:

> ```
> <runtime>
>   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>       <probing privatePath="ProbeFolder"/>
>    </assemblyBinding>
> </runtime>
> ```

- save the file
- restart kaxaml

Comment: This is an awesome solution and worked perfectly for me.  Thanks!

PS: A caveat, we use dmake to build our WPF apps, and we can't use the clr-namespace way of including an assembly (we have to use something like http://company.com/controls).  So, make sure you're using the more fragile method (clr-namespace) to get it to work.

Comment: This is the best solution I found when working with 3rd party control libraries because it includes the entire directory with out duplicating the files. Thanks for posting Todd.

Comment: All this does for me is give me an immediate crash when I launch Kaxaml, even when the target of ProbeFolder is empty. It seems to have a problem parsing the config file. I double-checked to make sure that I followed the steps correctly. I'm using the latest version of Kaxaml.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Todd White's solution (& this is future reference for myself too) your XAML in Kaxaml would reference a 3rd party library as follows:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:dxlc="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.v13.2"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <!-- Layout Control  Start -->
  <dxlc:LayoutControl Orientation="Horizontal">
  </dxlc:LayoutControl>
  <!-- Layout Control  End -->
</UserControl>
```